# Updating data on a window using serial communication with Raspberry Pi and pH sensor

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I'm having some problems updating data on a window using Tkinter. I'm using my raspberry pi and the Atlas Scientific pH Sensor with serial communication. The window works perfectly, but is not updating the data as I expected, so that, what am I doing wrong?. Here's the code. I really appreciate your help.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import serial

def datos(port):
    bus = ""
    while True:
        d = port.read()
        bus += d
        if d == '\r':   
            return bus

def sensor_pH():
    pH.set(datos(port))
    root.after(1000, sensor_pH)

port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 2)

port.write('L,1\r')#Command to turn the sensor's led on
port.write('C,1\r')#Command to read data, (pH), continuously every second

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
pH = IntVar()
bus = StringVar()

etpH = Label (root, text = 'pH: ') 
etpH.grid(row=0, column=0)
et1= Label(root, textvariable = pH)
et1.grid(row=0, column=9)

sensor_pH
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you turned off serial console on `ttyAMA0` ? You can use `sudo raspi-config` to do that, reboot and then try running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there and Welcome to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

You are not running sensor_pH in your code - this would be `sensor_pH()` for this one first.
Another thing - you are not using the correct scope in `def sensor_pH()`.

Try using

```
def sensor_pH():
    global root, pH, port
    pH.set(datos(port))
    root.after(1000, sensor_pH)
```

Variables from the `Main Routine` (global Scope) are not available directly in functions (local Scope). To use them in there without passing them as parameters you need to declare them global.

If you are wondering if the data is read correctly, use print statements either to stdout (`print()`) or to a logfile.

Another thing to show the serial connection data is to directly display it inside your `root` Window or a widget below it (e.g. `Tkinter.Text` or `Tkinter.ListBox` would be widgets that would come to my mind for that.

**bus** Variable used in your script:
 - Same here concerning scope
 - your are setting `bus=""` in `def datos(int port):`. Do you want to have a local variable here or do you want to use the `Tkinter.StringVar` you are declaring in your `Main Routine` ? **If** you want to use the StringVar, the correct initialization would be `bus.set("")`. Appending text to it would be `bus.set("%s%s"%(bus.get(),d))`. Instead of using the "old" `"%s"%var` you could also use `String.format()`.
 - If using StringVar for bus, you would need to change the assignment inside `sensor_pH` to `pH.set(datos(port).get())`